# How do we remove sorting from ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

From the below HTML i wanted to remove sorting from irModel.Answers.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="820px" data-ng-repeat="answer in irModel.Answers">
                <!--Option 1-->
                <tr data-ng-if="answer.QuestionId=='1'">
                    <td width="100%">
                        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td width = "2%"><input type="radio" ng-model="answer.ChoiceId" value="1" name="a1" ng-change="resetOptionAnswer('1')"/></td>
                                <td width = "98%">Request Independence Review</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!--Option 1.1-->
                <tr data-ng-if="answer.QuestionId=='1' && irModel.QuestionnaireId == 2" ng-show="getAnswerChoice('1')=='1'">
                    <td width="100%">
                        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="95%">Does the request pertain to a transaction that involves an existing audit client? <a href="#" onclick="OpenHelpPopup('125');return false;"><img id="popover02" src="../images/info_light_bg.gif" alt="" /></a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="95%">
                                    <input type="radio" ng-model="irModel.NewStandard" value="0" name="a3a" ng-change="resetModelStandard()" />No&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <input type="radio" ng-model="irModel.NewStandard" value="1" name="a3b" ng-change="resetModelStandard()" />Yes
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!--Option 1.1.1-->
                <tr data-ng-if="answer.QuestionId=='6'" ng-show="irModel.NewStandard=='1'">
                    <td width="100%">
                        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                             <tr>
                                <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="95%">Please select option: &nbsp;
                                    <select name="a3" style="min-width: 190px; height: 20px" ng-model="answer.ChoiceId" ng-change="setAnswertoNewAuditStandard()"
                                            ng-options="p.Id as p.Text for p in irModel.NewAuditStandard" >
                                        <option value="">---Select---</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!--Option 2-->
                <tr data-ng-if="answer.QuestionId=='1'">
                    <td width="100%">
                        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td width = "2%"><input type="radio" ng-model="answer.ChoiceId" value="2" name="a2" ng-disabled="!irModel.CanSkipIR" ng-change="resetOptionAnswer('1')"/></td>
                                <td width = "98%">Inter-firm exempt Audit engagement - Do not select this option if the US firm will issue an audit report on the US subsidiary, this option is only appropriate when our reporting is limited to an inter-firm report to another KPMG member firm and no others</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!--Option 2.1-->
                <tr data-ng-if="answer.QuestionId=='1'" ng-show="getAnswerChoice('1')=='2'">
                    <td width="100%">
                        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td width = "5%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width = "95%">Independence clearance is not required. Click Next to complete this step.:</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!--Option 3-->
                <tr data-ng-if="answer.QuestionId=='1'">
                    <td width="100%">
                        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td width = "2%"><input type="radio" ng-model="answer.ChoiceId" value="3" name="a3" ng-disabled="!irModel.CanSkipIR" ng-change="resetOptionAnswer('1')"/></td>
                                <td width = "98%">Independence Review Not Required</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!--Option 3.1-->
                <tr data-ng-if="answer.QuestionId=='1'" ng-show="getAnswerChoice('1')=='3'">
                    <td width="100%">
                        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td width = "5%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width = "95%">Is this an Audit engagement for which we will be reporting in accordance with PCAOB standards for the first time?</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width = "5%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width = "95%">
                                    <input type="radio" ng-model="irModel.Standard" value="0" name="a3a" ng-change="resetModelStandard()" />No&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <input type="radio" ng-model="irModel.Standard" value="1" name="a3b" ng-change="resetModelStandard()" />Yes
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!--Question 3.1.A-->
                <tr data-ng-if="answer.QuestionId=='3'" ng-show="irModel.Standard=='1'">
                    <td width="100%">
                        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td width = "8%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width = "92%">You must clear independence for all engagements involving an initial audit performed pursuant to PCAOB standards. Choose the first option above to continue.</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!--Question 3.1.B-->
                <tr data-ng-if="answer.QuestionId=='3'" ng-show="irModel.Standard=='0'">
                    <td width="100%">
                        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td width = "8%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width = "92%"><b>Reason Independence Review is not required:</b></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!--Option 3.1.B.1-->
                <tr data-ng-if="answer.QuestionId=='3'" ng-show="irModel.Standard=='0'">
                    <td width="100%">
                        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td width = "8%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width = "3%"><input type="radio" ng-model="answer.ChoiceId" ng-change="resetSubOptionAnswer()" value="1" name="a321" /></td>
                                <td width = "89%">Agreed-Upon Procedures (AUP) or other attestation engagement for an existing audit client when the new engagement does not require additional independence requirements (i.e. the standards for the AUP or attestation engagement are the same as or less than the standards for the audit engagement)</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!--Option 3.1.B.2-->
                <tr data-ng-if="answer.QuestionId=='3'" ng-show="irModel.Standard=='0'">
                    <td width="100%">
                        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td width = "8%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width = "3%"><input type="radio" ng-model="answer.ChoiceId" ng-change="resetSubOptionAnswer()" value="2" name="a322" /></td>
                                <td width = "89%">Audit or other attestation engagement for a subsidiary or component of an existing audit client (Do not select this option if the new engagement requires the firm to apply additional independence requirements or requires independence of a new entity such as the acquirer)</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!--Question 4-->
                <tr data-ng-if="answer.QuestionId=='3'" ng-show="getAnswerChoice('3')=='2'">
                    <td width="100%">
                        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td width = "11%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width = "3%"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="irModel.Affirm" name="a3bii2" /></td>
                                <td width = "86%">Your team is required to identify possible prohibited employment relationships. Check here to affirm you have or will identify whether:</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width = "11%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width = "3%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width = "86%">
                                    <ul style="margin: 10; padding: 0;">
                                        <li>A close family member of a covered person at KPMG serves in an accounting or financial
                                            reporting oversight role at your new audit client. </li>
                                        <li>A former partner who is in a financial reporting oversight or accounting role at
                                            your new audit client had a remaining financial interest with KPMG. </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <b> NOTE:</b> You are required to document your conclusions on these situations
                                    in a memo and attach it to the corresponding CEAC Engagement Evaluation so it can
                                    be cleared by your BUPPP.
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!--Option 3.1.B.3-->
                <tr data-ng-if="answer.QuestionId=='3'" ng-show="irModel.Standard=='0'">
                    <td width="100%">
                        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td width = "8%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width = "3%"><input type="radio" ng-model="answer.ChoiceId" value="3" ng-change="resetSubOptionAnswer()" name="a323" /></td>
                                <td width = "89%">New company formed by existing audit client</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!--Question 4-->
                <tr data-ng-if="answer.QuestionId=='3'" ng-show="getAnswerChoice('3')=='3'">
                    <td width="100%">
                        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td width = "11%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width = "3%"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="irModel.Affirm" name="a3bii2" /></td>
                                <td width = "86%">Your team is required to identify possible prohibited employment relationships. Check here to affirm you have or will identify whether:</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width = "11%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width = "3%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width = "86%">
                                    <ul style="margin: 10; padding: 0;">
                                        <li>A close family member of a covered person at KPMG serves in an accounting or financial
                                            reporting oversight role at your new audit client. </li>
                                        <li>A former partner who is in a financial reporting oversight or accounting role at
                                            your new audit client had a remaining financial interest with KPMG. </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <b> NOTE:</b> You are required to document your conclusions on these situations
                                    in a memo and attach it to the corresponding CEAC Engagement Evaluation so it can
                                    be cleared by your BUPPP.
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!--Option 3.1.B.4-->
                <tr data-ng-if="answer.QuestionId=='3'" ng-show="irModel.Standard=='0'">
                    <td width="100%">
                        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td width = "8%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width = "3%"><input type="radio" ng-model="answer.ChoiceId" value="4" ng-change="resetSubOptionAnswer()" name="a324" /></td>
                                <td width = "89%">Continuance of an AUP or other attestation engagement where the team is able to conclude that there are no services or other relationships that have a bearing on independence</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!--Option 3.1.B.5-->
                <tr data-ng-if="answer.QuestionId=='3'" ng-show="irModel.Standard=='0'">
                    <td width="100%">
                        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td width = "8%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width = "3%"><input type="radio" ng-model="answer.ChoiceId" value="5" ng-change="resetSubOptionAnswer();focusInOut();" name="a325" /></td>
                                <td width = "89%">Other</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!--Question 5-->
                <tr data-ng-if="answer.QuestionId=='5'" ng-show="getAnswerChoice('3')=='5'">
                    <td width="100%">
                        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td width = "14%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width = "86%">The Independence Clearance Team will contact you to assist you in supporting this conclusion.</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width = "14%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width = "86%">
                                    <div style="float: left"><font color="red">*</font>Reason:</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <!--<textarea ng-init="getHolderTextBlur('5', 'Provide the reason that you do not believe Independence Review is required');" ng-focus="getHolderTextFocus('5', 'Provide the reason that you do not believe Independence Review is required');" ng-blur="getHolderTextBlur('5', 'Provide the reason that you do not believe Independence Review is required');" rows="5" cols="60" ng-model="answer.AnswerText" name="OtherReasonIRNotRequired" ></textarea>-->
                                    <textarea placeholder="Provide the reason that you do not believe Independence Review is required" rows="5" cols="60" ng-model="answer.AnswerText" name="OtherReasonIRNotRequired" ></textarea>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: Can you please edit the question to show only the relevant code, so that your question becomes clearer? I have no idea which sorting you are refering to.

Comment: The data isn't sorted by the HTML, if it is sorted by whatever retrieves the data, you can't 'undo' the sort

Answer (score 0):

Use like below for sorting:

data-ng-repeat="answer in irModel.Answers | orderBy":

For more details visit:

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_filter_orderby.asp